# Inside elements are outside navbar in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling with the collapsible navbar, specifically the right side of it. Here's the code regarding it:

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                            
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" >Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn" >Sign Up</a></li>                                
        </ul>
   </div>
```

I noticed that it was sticking awkwardly to the right of my main body. I gave it dashed borders and it yielded this.

[image]

Is it an easy fix? I think I used the navbar-btn property correctly. I also have tried to use

```
margin-left:-20px
```

but to no avail. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the HTML provided by you, this is a perfectly normal behavior

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5c97z/)

`navbar` is sticking to the right of main body because of class `navbar-right`. Remove this and  [it wont align to right](http://jsfiddle.net/5c97z/1/)

If you are getting a layout moving out of design, then it might be because of some custom CSS or some incorrect markup pattern!

Comment: Thanks. I know that navbar-right makes it float right, and I want that, but do you happen to know what would make buttons in specific become unruly like this?

Comment: @Kragalon : this is definately some some css messing with your layout...can you please post any custom CSS that you used and also the HTML markup for the *header* of your layout?